# How to mock api calls in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I am using `__mocks__` directory to create mock for my api module and using `jest.mock("../path/api");` in my test file to mock the api module.
I get this error when I run the test

```
renders without crashing

expect(received).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Received has type:  function
Received has value: [Function fetchData]
```

My test code is as below

```
//__tests__/App.test.tsx

import * as React from "react";
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "../App";
import * as client from "../path/api";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";

jest.useFakeTimers();
jest.mock("../path/api");

test("renders without crashing", async () => {
  render(<App />);
  act(() => {
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(4000);
  });
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(client.fetchData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
  const text = screen.getByText(/someTextFromFetchedData/i);
  expect(text).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

The actual api call is like this

```
//..path/api.ts

function fetchData(): Promise<IData[]> {
  return fetch("url").then((response) =>
    response.json()
  );
}

export { fetchData };
```

and the mock for api is this

```
//..path/__mocks__/api.ts
function fetchData(): Promise<IData[]> {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      return Math.random() <= 0.1
        ? reject(new Error("Fetch error"))
        : resolve(mockData);
    }, 3000);
  });
}
export { fetchData };
```

What might be the issue?

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/rahulcyadav/jest-api-mock/tree/main/

Comment: How did you use `fetchData` in your `App` component?

Comment: @slideshowp2 it is called inside `useEffect()` hook and sets the `data, error and loading` states...`App` renders data and error/loading states accordingly